# When were third person pronouns added to French?

Tags: pronoms, histoire, évolution

[Proto-Indo-European_language#Pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language#Pronoun):

> PIE had personal pronouns in the first and second grammatical person,
>   but not the third person, where demonstrative pronouns were used
>   instead

[Personal_pronoun#Person_and_number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_pronoun#Person_and_number):

> Some languages do not have third-person personal pronouns, instead
>   using demonstratives (e.g. Macedonian) or full noun phrases. Latin
>   used demonstratives rather than third-person pronouns (in fact the
>   third-person pronouns in the Romance languages are descended from the
>   Latin demonstratives).

When were third person pronouns added to French?

Comment: See [this very interesting thread](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/when-and-how-did-french-become-a-non-null-subject-language). The "when" is the Middle Ages, but the why and how are very interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd  person pronouns were gradually introduced in [Old French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_French) onwards, their use had become generalized  in [Middle French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_French).

From Albert Cohen, *[Histoire d'une langue, le français](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Histoire_d_une_langue_le_fran%C3%A7ais.html?id=kixcAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)*

« Dès l'ancien français, les pronoms sujets de première et deuxième personnes sont généralement employés à côté du verbe ; les pronoms de troisième personne ne sont généralement pas employés, notamment dans le cas fréquent où le substantif sujet, après avoir figuré une fois en début de phrase n'est pas répété ensuite, ainsi « l'homme naît, grandit, vieillit.
Les pronoms reproduisent les pronoms indépendants du latin pour la 1<sup>er</sup> et la 2<sup>e</sup> personne, et pour la 3<sup>e</sup> personne le démonstratif *ille*; certains ont des formes accentuées comme sujet autonome ou comme complément avec préposition, au contraire non accentuées et raccourcies comme sujet ou régime (d'objet sujet ou d'attribution) joint étroitement au verbe que n'avait pas le latin. »
[...]
En moyen français les désinences verbales étaient déjà bien usées et « la distinction des personnes se fait principalement au moyen des pronoms personnels joints au verbe. Dans toute l'histoire du français (sauf un léger arrêt et même recul au 16<sup>e</sup> siècle dans des textes comportant une affectation d'archaïsme) le pronom sujet a été de plus en plus employé et de plus en plus rapproché du verbe.
Finalement, aux trois personnes, le pronom figure régulièrement devant le verbe (excepté à la 3<sup>e</sup> personne exprimée par un nom, comme «le roi boit ».

---

The following is a personal rendering of Albert Cohen's words.

1st and 2nd person personal pronouns were used in Old French but 3rd person pronouns were not since, after having been explicit once, it was not usually repeated.

In Middle French most of the verb endings that used to help distinguish persons had disappeared and therefore personal pronouns were regularly used next to the verbs for the three persons. The only case it was not used in the third person is when the full noun was used.